# Function returned from another function

Tags: javascript, function, first-class-functions

I observed a difference in output when trying to run similar function.

```js
function func1(){
     function sum(){
        console.log(2+5);
    }
    return sum();
}
func1();

function func2(){
    return (function sum(){
       console.log(2+5);
   })
    
}

func2();
```

From func1, the output is 7. But from func2, nothing is there in the console. What is the difference in both functions as both are returned from the function? Why did one get invoked and another didn't?

Comment: Func1 calls the function, and thus returns the returned value. Func2 does not call it, but just returns the function.

Comment: Because you did not _call_ the function, that `func2` returns. This needs to be `func2()();`

Comment: @CBroe, or another way to understand, with perhaps less confusing syntax than `()()` is to think of it like `result = func2(); result();`  Because `func2` _returns a function_, you must also call _that_ function that was returned.

Comment: Because `func1` does not return a function but `func2` returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From func1, the output is 7. But from func2, nothing is there in the console. What is the difference in both functions as both are returned from the function?
Answer the difference between both is, the first one's return statement **calls** the the sum function.

In the second one the function's definition is returned hence it's defined but not called resulting into no output.

Answer (score 2):

`func2` returns a function and after calling it, you get the result.

```js
function func1() {
    function sum() {
        console.log(2 + 5);
    }
    return sum();
}

func1();

function func2() {
    return (function sum() {
        console.log(2 + 5);
    });
}

func2()();            // call function
console.log(func2()); // see function declaration
```